# array.includes( () => {} ) as a function

Tags: javascript

Is there a method like includes that only searches for an element in an array but allows you to see the elements that are being iterating on?

for example: I have the following array:

```
const arr = [{ color: 'red' },{ color: 'blue' },{ color: 'pink' },{ color: 'green' }]
```

I want to check if the `arr` holds an element with the value of `pink`: so I thought if there's something like this in JavaScript:

```
arr.includes( (el, index)=> el.color == 'pink' )
```

which then returns a boolean, either true or false.

Is there a method like that in JavaScript? if not, what about **lodash**?

Comment: `arr.some(el => el.color === "pink")` returns true or false

Comment: I marked my question as a duplicate, but I think that it should be separated in a stand alone thread, because it's a general question and not related to a particular thing to achieve, How can I unmark it from being duplicated?

Comment: You can't directly. You can edit your question, explain why you think it is different and then mark the "_Submit for review_" checkbox. After that the community will review and vote to reopen when they agree with it. I don't give it much chance though. It answers the question perfectly after all.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want find:

```
if (arr.find(el => el.color === "pink")) console.log("it's there");
```

Comment: `some` would be better, because it returns a boolean.